# Best way to display results of while loop

Tags: php, arrays, forms

Edit **
Ok lets see if i can make this clear :) sorry not been explaining properly.

I have the below while loop, was hoping someone might be able to tell me the best way to display the results, I need it to show the colour name (***edit*** and the size as array key which i will then explode later to seperate the colour and size*) and then the value from the input.  The results are sent to the next page via post.

```
    <?php

$colour_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT colour_variation.*, colours.* FROM colour_variation INNER JOIN colours ON colour_variation.colour_id=colours.colour_id WHERE product_code='$recordID'");
while($colour_row = mysqli_fetch_array($colour_result))
  {
 ?> 
<tr><td valign="middle"><img src="resources/images/colours/<?php echo $colour_row['colour_image']; ?>" width="35" height="35"></td><td width="100"><?php echo $colour_row['colour_name']; ?>
<center><?php if($colour_row['colour_name'] !== '') { echo('<input type="hidden" size="20" name="' . $colour_row['colour_name'] . '" placeholder="Qty">');
     } else { echo(''); } ?> </center></td>

    <td><center><?php if($colour_row['s'] !== '') { echo('<input type="text" size="2" name="s[]" placeholder="Qty">');
     } else { echo(''); } ?> </center></td>

    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>


<?php } ?>
```

I would like to be able to do something like name=" . $colour_row['colour_name'] . '_s[]'"
but the problem is that i don't know what all the colour names will be.

At the minute i have it : name="xs[]" as an array and displayed it like this :

```
$arr_s = $_POST['s'];

foreach ($arr_s as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>$value</td></tr>\n";
}
```

or :

```
 $arr_s = $_POST['s'];

echo 'Small:';
print_r(array_filter($arr_s));
```

but that doesn't give me the colour_name just the position in the array.

On the second page i want the array to display all non empty values like so:
colour name : S : input value

*** Alternatively : i have the colour name as a hidden field, if i could display the colour name then s: value; m: value; l: value; etc. missing out the empty values.  then next line display next colour name followed by sizes etc.

Hopefully i've explained a little better.

Thanks v much

Comment: try to use != instead of !==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
$arr_s = array(
 "red" => "#f00",
 "blue" => "#00f",
);

foreach ($arr_s as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>$value</td></tr>\n";
}
```

produces

```
<tr><td>red</td><td>#f00</td></tr>
<tr><td>blue</td><td>#00f</td></tr>
```

Can you show output of `var_dump($colour_row)` ?

Comment: thank you i have already been able to display the output of the array, however the main problem is that as shown about in posted code each form name is made up of records from mysql name="s_' . $colour_row['colour_name'] . '".  i can make then all show in a long list.  but i want to be able to use the colour name and then list the sizes and values

Comment: each form element: echo('<input type="text" size="2" name="xs[]" placeholder="Qty">'); has the array for the size, which i can now get to display on the next page, successfully with array_filter to get rid of empty values, however as the key to each value i need the $colour_row['colour_name'] to show instead of just 0, 1, 2, etc.

Comment: $arr_xs = $_POST['xs'];
$arr_s = $_POST['s'];
$arr_m = $_POST['m'];
$arr_l = $_POST['l'];
$arr_xl = $_POST['xl'];
$arr_xxl = $_POST['xxl'];
echo 'Extra Small:';
print_r(array_filter($arr_xs));
echo '<br />';
echo 'Small:';
print_r(array_filter($arr_s));
echo '<br />';
echo 'Medium:';
print_r(array_filter($arr_m));
echo '<br />';
echo 'Large:';
print_r(array_filter($arr_l));
echo '<br />';
echo 'Extra Large:';
print_r(array_filter($arr_xl));
echo '<br />';
echo 'Extra Extra Large:';
print_r(array_filter($arr_xxl));

Comment: Sorry, it's not yet clear, to me... you should print (with "print_r($arr_s)", for example) the value of your input variable just after it has been read from $_POST; then print the code you use to extract the values from it; then print the output of that code; then say what you should expect. As a general rule, please avoid using too much irrelevant code: do not show $arr_xs, $arr_s, $arr_m, ... but only one instance... :-)